# Why if Action returns no value does it require a return statement?

Tags: c#

Consider the following:

```
public Action MyAction()
{
   //Take some action
}
```

Now notice:

[image]

However we also get this compile time error:

[image]

I would expect better compile time handling of this, or am I missing something?

Comment: MyAction is a method that returns an Action...

Comment: you are making a method which requires an `Action` object to be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Action` itself may not require a `return` statement, but the `MyAction` method does.  Why?  Because it has a return value:

```
public Action MyAction()
{
    //Take some action
}
```

The compiler isn't interested in digging into the details of what that return value is or how it will behave after it's been returned.  It just enforces that a non-`void` method returns an instance of the correct type.

Comment: To be correct, it does not requires `return`, it requires that end of method had been unreachable. It can `throw` or even hung `for(;;);`.